# Is it possible to preset Form POST Body (multipart) with Plain Javascript without doing Ajax/XHR or Fetch?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, csrf, same-origin-policy

I'm currently working on a Hacking Challenge in a Security Course.

It is required to do a **multipart/form-data** POST Request as an CSRF (trick the user to visit my HTML/JS and redirecting her with authenticated Session to do something harmful).

As the necessary `Allow-Origins` Header is missing it's not possible to do it with Ajax/XHR or Fetch.

That leaves me to the question: Can I append Formdata or something similar to a DOM-based Form and submit it like a browser initiated Submit that will bypass the CORS restrictions?

This is my initial idea. The POST Request runs as intended, but the file payload isn't appended to the body like it should?!

```js
<html> 
        <body>
        <form id="myForm" method="POST" action="http://vuln-app/api/v1/process" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
                <input type="file" id="fileinput"> 
                <input type="submit" value="Submit request" /> 
        </form> 
        <script> 
yml = ` 
vulnerable yml code
`
        var ymlBlob = new Blob([yml], { type: "application/yml" });
        
        form = document.forms[0];
        var fd = new FormData(form);

        fd.append("fileinput", ymlBlob, "description.yml");

        form.submit();
        </script>
        </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your `<form>` element would need [the `enctype` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-enctype) set to `multipart/formdata` for the files to be uploaded.

Comment: thank you, yes that is true, but apart from that, things that are working here in the `XHR` context, doesn't work here. For example replace the fd.append with a very simple string: `fd.append("custom-field", "this is test body content")`

Comment: You won't be able to bypass the CORS restrictions in publicly distributed browsers. Also, when you append to `fd` - this does not append to the `form`, these are 2 separate objects.

Comment: okay, when the browser itself gets redirected to the domain by a submit and the browser as a active session in the target application it will surely use stored cookies?! Okay I linked formdata and form by doing `var fd = new FormData(form);` but I guess like in XHR/Fetch I have to explicitly add the formdata to the request object.